# Where to start Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning

I've recently stumbled upon machine learning, generating user recommendations based on user data, generating text teaser based on an article. Although there are tons of framework that does this(Apache Mahout, Duine framework and more) I wanted to know the core principles, core algorithms of machine learning and in the future implement my own implementation of machine learning.

Where do I actually start learning Machine Learning as its basics or Machine Learning starting with concepts then to implementation? Although I have an weak to average math skills(I think that this will not hurt? If So what branches of mathematics should I study before Jumping to Machine Learning?)

Note that this is not related to my academics rather I want to learn this as an independent researcher and I am quite fascinated how machine learning works

Comment: The python [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) library is a good thing to be aware of.  I've heard the documentation is very good, and it will give you an overview of many standard topics in machine learning.

Answer (score 8):

You can start machine learning from [Coursera Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml)

Comment: do I need to know in depth statistics?

Comment: No, not at all. You don't need any prior knowledge of statistics. Only basic linear algebra like matrix multiplication and some very elementary calculus.

Comment: so I guess I need to re-learn my basic statistics , basic linear algebra and calculus?

Comment: Yes. But there is a nice review of these materials in the course.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll just immediately start this course! thanks!

Comment: Probabilistic Graphical Models is also a great course.

Answer (score 5):

Try to read Hastie, Tishirani, Friedman "Elements of Statistical Learning". It is a nice book. If you are specifically interested in unsupervised learning, then try the quite new Kogan "Introduction to Clustering Large and High Dimensional Data": algorithms are explicitly given.

Comment: If that Hastie et al book is too math heavy, (some of) the same authors have a simpler book, with R in its title.

Comment: this is a very good comment: the simpler book with R examples is an excellent introduction to the subject.

Answer (score 5):

If you need some ideas for practical projects to immerse yourself into machine learning, you might be interested in looking at [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596529325) by Toby Segeran.

Answer (score 3):

Coursera Machine Learning is one of the best places to start, but there are countless resources. [There's a huge, wonderful open list of links at Github](https://github.com/josephmisiti/awesome-machine-learning). I definitely recommend you take a look at it.

There are also another great resources online, like those I list below:

- [In-depth introduction to machine learning in 15 hours of expert videos](http://www.dataschool.io/15-hours-of-expert-machine-learning-videos/)
- Deep Learning Tutorial (@ ufldl.Stanford.edu/tutorial/, can't post the link because I'm out of mana, I mean, not enough reputation yet).

Hope it helps!

Comment: When you get enough rep you can come back and edit in the link!

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen yeah, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to great resources already mentioned, I highly recommend Kevin Murphy's book: "Machine Learning: A Probabilistic Perspective".

For implementations of machine learning algorithms, have a look at:

- https://github.com/probml/pmtk3
- https://github.com/PRML/PRMLT

Answer (score 2):

[Machine learning crash course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/) from google is good place to start. Also as mentioned above, [Machine Learning](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning) course from Coursera is also great material on machine Learning.

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend the course [Learning from data](https://work.caltech.edu/telecourse) by Yaser Abu-Mostafa from Caltech. An excellent course!

Answer (score 0):

If you really like to learn ML Algos in depth and from the scratch and want to try to implement them yourself, so you can learn and understand them better, I recommend Cornel University ML course.

For me this is thus far the best course I've ever seen on ML.