# The math part of machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I want to start learning the math part of machine learning so that i can optimise models with my sense of understanding . Any good sources you can recommend

Comment: IMO: Learn real analysis, then probability, and then statistics.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425230/27978

Comment: Buy the very recent and excellent "Linear Algebra and Learning from Data" by Gibert Strang, Wellesley-Cambridge editor, 2019.